# Prop type `children` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from React.PropTypes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsbyjs

Использую Gatsby js версии 1.0 для своего приложения. Консоль выдала ошибку: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это странно, поскольку в компоненте для 'children' прописывается свойство о том, что они функции. Проблема в том, что это Gatsby-Starter-Blog, то есть это стартовый пакет, в котором почему-то вылазит баг и не собирается нормально проект. Я оставила им Issue, но всё еще жду ответ.
Компонента ниже. Буду благодарна за любые идеи, что идет не так.

```
import React from "react"
import Link from "gatsby-link"
import { Container } from "react-responsive-grid"

import { rhythm, scale } from "../utils/typography"

class Template extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { location, children } = this.props
    let header
    if (location.pathname === "/") {
      header = (
        <h1 >
          <Link to={"/"}>
            Gatsby Starter Blog
          </Link>
        </h1>
      )
    } else {
      header = (
        <h3>
          <Link to={"/"} >
            Gatsby Starter Blog
          </Link>
        </h3>
      )
    }
    return (
      <Container>
        {header}
        {children()}
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

Template.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.function,
  location: React.PropTypes.object,
  route: React.PropTypes.object,
}

export default Template
```

Answer (score 0):

Свойства `function` у PropTypes нет... `React.PropTypes.function`, скорее всего вы хотели `children: React.PropTypes.func`. Если код Template ваш, то это ваша ошибка.

Comment: нет, код не мой. он "из коробки". спасибо, сейчас попробую